# How to write regular expression for negating the character set [a-zA-Z0-9-._,\s]

Tags: xml, regex, perl, regex-negation

I need to write a regular expresssion for a string to match [a-zA-z0-9-._,\s] character set only. Other than the mentioned character set , it should throw an error. Also, the length of the string could be 30 characters only. I implemented word wrap also. But, i am not able to throw error if the string is other than the mentioned character set.
Any help would be much appreciated!

My string looks like :

```
   shubhwork1234  567$#@!%^&*()<>:"-,._abadcew
```

My code should throw an error - stating that only [a-zA-z0-9-._,\s] character set is allowed.

If my string is below : then there should be NO error.

```
   shubhworkwwwwwwwww1234567-,._  abadcew
```

My code looks like :

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   my $prodname;
   my $temp_str;
   my $space = ' '; # word wrap done usign space character
   $prodname = "shubhwork1234  567$#@!%^&*()<>:"-,._abadcew";
   print (Product name not specified-name 1\n) unless($prodname);
   print "\n Product name is : $prodname";

   # For Product name , only 30 characters are allowed.
   print "\nLength of product name : ",length($prodname),"\n";    
   if(length($prodname) > 30)
   {
        print "\n Hello world";
            $temp_str = substr($prodname,0,40);
            print qq| Length of Product Name can be 40 characters.Terminating rest of the string\n|);

  #Handling xml special characters >,<,&,",'
     $temp_str =~ s/&/&amp;/g; 
     $temp_str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
     $temp_str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
     $temp_str =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
     $temp_str =~ s/'/&apos;/g;
     $temp_str =~ s/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19]//g;

     # Word wrap
     my $rindx = rindex($temp_str,$space);
     $temp_str = substr($temp_str,0,$rindx);
     print "\n Sting temp is : $temp_str";

     #Here I ma not able to use negate properly for the character set. 
     if ($temp_str =~ m/^[a-zA-Z0-9]-._,\s*/)
     {
        print (qq| For product name : Invalid Input : Only [a-zA-Z0-9-._,] and spaces are allowed\n|);
     }                  
       $prodname = $temp_str; 
      print "\n assigning string is :",$prodname;
     }
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this XML? Are you perhaps looking for a regex that conforms to the XSD or XPath rules for regular expressions? Otherwise, the tag is just confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing square bracket in wrong spot, you forgot the trailing `\z`, and you forgot to negate.

```
if ($temp_str !~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9-._,\s]*\z/)  # Doesn't consist of good characters
```

or you could use

```
if ($temp_str =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9-._,\s]/)  # Contains a non-good character
```

Note that `\s` matches a number of different whitespace character, not just the space.

Comment: Thank you so much! But, what does \z means in the above regular expression?

Comment: I should check condition for <>"' etc before or afterwards. My prodname variable comes from an xml. So, I SHOULD DO A CHECK for apos, <,> etc before only or afterwards.

Comment: End of string. Most people misuse `$` for that purpose, but `$` means `\n?\z`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also want to check the length, you don't need to negate it.  You can just check that the entire string is 30 or fewer of the allowed characters:

```
/\A[a-zA-z0-9-._,\s]{0,30}\z/
```

Comment: what does \A and \z means ? Could you please explain ?